# ArrayList<Item> getDbItems

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that will return the content of three tables from the database as an ArrayList using for a if. I have the following code:

```
public ArrayList<Item> getDbItems()
    {
        ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayFromDatabase.length(); i++)
        {
        if ( ArrayList<Item>= new ArrayList<>()[i].type == WEAPON_ID)
        {
            list.add(new Items.Weapon(ArrayFromDatabase[i].id, ArrayFromDatabase[i].name,/*..........*/ ))
        }
        if (ArrayFromDatabase[i].type == ARMOR_ID)
        {
            list.add(new Items.Armor(), /*............*/)
        }
        if (ArrayFromDatabase[i].type == POTION_ID)
        {
            list.add(new Items.Potion(), /*............*/)
        }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I do not know exactly what I have "ArrayFromDatabase". Can you tell me it? For example, this is my entity class Weapon:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dke.ps.Tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author michal
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "weapon")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByItemid", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.itemid = :itemid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByName", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByDescription", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.description = :description")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByIcon", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.icon = :icon")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByType", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.type = :type")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByPower", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.power = :power")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByPrice", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.price = :price")})
public class Weapon implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemid")
    private Integer itemid;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;
    @Column(name = "power")
    private Integer power;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemid", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private ItemsId itemsId;

    public Weapon() {
    }

    public Weapon(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public Integer getItemid() {
        return itemid;
    }

    public void setItemid(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(Integer power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ItemsId getItemsId() {
        return itemsId;
    }

    public void setItemsId(ItemsId itemsId) {
        this.itemsId = itemsId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (itemid != null ? itemid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Weapon)) {
            return false;
        }
        Weapon other = (Weapon) object;
        if ((this.itemid == null && other.itemid != null) || (this.itemid != null && !this.itemid.equals(other.itemid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.dke.ps.Tables.Weapon[ itemid=" + itemid + " ]";
    }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I really don't like that approach, you should use those named queries to get your arrayList of weapons, potions, etc... anyway, why you don't add here the code to populate this ArrayFromDatabase?

Comment: Do you know about JPA/Hibernate/EclipseLink at all? If not, you should learn the technique before you use it.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have to use this solution. Do you know how it will be?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood from your question is that you need data from different tables i.e. Weapon, Armor, Portion having corresponding classes in hibernate

To get the result, what you can do is

1. Get data from weapon table (using hibernate will give the data in form of objects)
2. Populate in the list
3. Repeat step 1 & 2 for Armor and Potion too

Comment: Thanks for your advice, could you show me how it will look exactly?